# VBA - How to add a collection to a collection of collections

Tags: vba, excel, collections, ms-word

I am trying to create code to represent a form document using VBA in Word 2007. I have created classes to represent Section, QuestionSet and Question.

So I have 15 Sections. I have created a function to create each 'Section' Object add it to the 'Sections' Collection then destroy the object, the result being that the objects remain persistent in the collection (or something).

Is it possible to use the same method to add collections to collections or would I have to define each collection explictly?

Code in Module:

```
Public Sections As Collection

Function DefineSection(ByVal SectionName As String)

    Set Section = New clsSection
    Section.myName = SectionName
    Sections.Add Section, SectionName

End Function


Function DefineQuestionSet(ByVal SectionName As String, ByVal Name As String, ByVal NoOfQuestions As Integer, ByVal IsMutuallyExclusive As Boolean, Optional ByVal DependentOnSection As String)

    Dim Qsets As Collection

    Set Qsets = New Collection
    Set QuestionSet = New clsQuestionSet

    QuestionSet.Name = Name
    QuestionSet.NoOfQuestions = NoOfQuestions
    QuestionSet.MutuallyExclusive = IsMutuallyExclusive

    If Not (DependentOnSection) = "" Then
        QuestionSet.DependentOnSection = DependentOnSection
    End If

    Qsets.Add QuestionSet
    Sections.Item(SectionName).Add Qsets

End Function
```

Then this is called via:

```
Sub Initilise()

    Set Sections = New Collection

    DefineSection "PersonalDetails"
    DefineQuestionSet "PersonalDetails", "PersonalDetails", 29, False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**.  You can absolutely add collections to collections to collections ad infinitum.  The code you have posted looks like it should work just from glancing through it.  Are you having specific problems?

*UPDATE*:  VBA only passes around *references* to objects.  <strike>**If you explicitly destroy an object after assigning it to a collection (eg, `Set myObj = Nothing`) then you will also be destroying the object inside the collection.**</strike>

[EDIT]: Apparently this is not true.  From [this website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198465) (first linked by Stevo in the comments):

> In order to use collections to manage
>   class objects, you must do the
>   following:

- Create an instance of the class
- Set the properties and methods of the class
- Add the class to a public collection
- Unload the instance of the class

> You might expect that unloading
>   the instance of the class results in
>   the class being closed and terminated.
>   However, the class object persists
>   because you add it to a collection,
>   which then owns the reference to the
>   class. This is a very powerful
>   technique that allows you to control
>   object references through a
>   collection; the class object does not
>   terminate until you remove it from the
>   collection.

*UPDATE*:  There's no reason why you can't add a collection to an object.  You just need the class your object is instantiated from to support such a method.  For example, in your `clsSection` class module you need an `Add` method which adds objects passed to it to a collection stored in the `clsSection`:

```
Private QSetsColl As Collection

Public Sub Add(QSets As Object)
    If QSetsColl Is Nothing Then Set QSetsColl = New Collection
    QSetsColl.Add QSets
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've changed the code for now, to try and just create independent collections - however I got an error from the line
    'Sections.Item(SectionName).Add Qsets' in the 'DefineQuestionSet' function.

Comment: Just to clarify, the code adds the objects to the collection and then destroys the instance of the object, but it remains persistent in the collection, so I don't have to keep track of the objects. Is it the same for the collections? i.e. create collection B, add to parent collection A, destroy collection B, but because it's added to collection A, it remains an 'item' in collection A.

Comment: the error message is the ever enigmatic 'object doesn't support this property or method'

Comment: Thanks, that helped me work it out. Although on the point about objects being destroyed, but the properties remaining part of the collection: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198465

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I learned something new today.  I updated my answer to reflect the info in the link.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I now understand what's actually happening to the object when in the collection! - With respect to the design of my code - I have decided that I need to create a container collection to hold a collection and the meta information about the collection, this should give me what I want, although reading your response, I'll have a look at containing it within the object (i was shying away from that, for some reason) - Anyhow, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim masterCollection As New collection
    masterCollection.Add "first key", createDetailCollection()
    masterCollection.Add "second key", createDetailCollection()
    masterCollection.Add "third key", createDetailCollection()

End Sub
```

The follow function return a initializated collection

```
Function createDetailCollection()
    Dim collection As New collection
    createCollection = collezioneBuy
End Function
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use `Set createCollection = collezioneBuy` instead of `createCollection = collezioneBuy` in `createDetailCollection()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer now, but if someone could clarify that would be helpful.

I think what the code is doing is trying to add a collection to an object - which obviously won't work. So I need to create a collection which I can add the object AND the collection to. etc.