# Adding a custom class collection to another custom class collection

Tags: vba, excel, collections

Ok to start off, I read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116460/vba-how-to-add-a-collection-to-a-collection-of-collections).
It is close although it doesn't answer my specific question. This talks about taking smaller collections and adding items to a larger main collection. Then destroying the smaller collection.

I have two definitions under Class Modules.

TimeDet

```
Option Explicit
Public recDate As String
Public recQty As String
Public recDieNo As String
Public recCatID As String
Public recCatName As String
Public recGroupID As String
Public recGroupName As String
```

TimeRec

```
Option Explicit
Private objTimeRec As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set objTimeRec = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set objTimeRec = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = objTimeRec.[_NewEnum]
End Property

Public Sub Add(obj As TimeDet)
    objTimeRec.Add obj
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(Index As Variant)
    objTimeRec.Remove Index
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(Index As Variant) As TimeDet
    Set Item = objTimeRec.Item(Index)
End Property

Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = objTimeRec.Count
End Property

Public Sub Clear()
    Set objTimeRec = New Collection
End Sub

Public Sub FillFromArray(Arr As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, obj As TimeDet
    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        Set obj = New TimeDet
        obj.recDate = Arr(i, 1)
        obj.recQty = Arr(i, 2)
        obj.recDieNo = Arr(i, 3)
        obj.recCatID = Arr(i, 4)
        obj.recCatName = Arr(i, 5)
        obj.recGroupID = Arr(i, 6)
        obj.recGroupName = Arr(i, 7)
        Me.Add obj
    Next

End Sub
```

Then in the code I am using it this way:

```
Sub Test()
Dim RecSet1 As TimeRec, Record As TimeDet
Dim fSet1 As TimeRec, fRecord As TimeDet
Dim repArray() As Variant
Dim startDT As Date, endDT As Date, dieNo As String

repArray() = Sheet4.Range("A2:G" & Sheet4.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)

Set RecSet1 = New TimeRec
Set fSet1 = New TimeRec

RecSet1.FillFromArray (repArray())

startDT = "1-1-2015"
endDT = "1-1-2016"
dieNo = "16185"

For Each Record In RecSet1
    If Record.recDate <= endDT And Record.recDate >= startDT And Record.recDieNo = dieNo Then
        fSet1.Add (Record)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I am getting an error when I try to add the Record object to the fSet1 object.
"Object doesn't support this method or property"

The Record object is Type TimeDet which as you can see up in the class module my Add method is expecting type TimeDet.

Either I am  missing something very simple and have blinders on, or this is a bigger issue.

The array has 200,000 records roughly. I am attempting to create a smaller subset of filtered data. Maybe I am approaching this from the wrong way.

Comment: is your Class Name Module TimeRec ? is the first `Set RecSet1 = New TimeRec` working ?

Comment: Yes - I have all the objects in the watch. RecSet1 and Record all have the correct types and Data in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is not at `Add` but at `For Each`

Most likely you copied your TimeRec Class. In VBA, you can't create enumerable classes inside the VBE (VBA IDE).  There's a different way of creating Enumerable classes.

Open a notepad, copy all your class code and then add this attribute to `NewEnum` property `Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4`

Then import the class.

This is always hidden in VBA code, but can be seen in text editors. 
Also add this attribute to `Item` property, it will make it default and allows syntax like ClassName(1)

`Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0`

So , your code in text editor/ notepad should be:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Class1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit
Private objTimeRec As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set objTimeRec = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set objTimeRec = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Set NewEnum = objTimeRec.[_NewEnum]
End Property

Public Sub Add(obj As Class2)
    objTimeRec.Add obj
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(Index As Variant)
    objTimeRec.Remove Index
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(Index As Variant) As Class2
Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0
    Set Item = objTimeRec.Item(Index)
End Property

Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = objTimeRec.Count
End Property

Public Sub Clear()
    Set objTimeRec = New Collection
End Sub
```

Comment: You are correct! I did Copy paste that example, so without the import I wouldn't have gotten the hidden settings. It is still giving me the same error though after Importing and changing the names accordingly.

Comment: changing the names? Avoid making changes to this class in  VBE. make all the change in the notepad.

Comment: Correct - I changed the class2 refs you had back to TimeDet. I also set the VB_name to TimeRec, then imported the file.

Comment: FYI, I think this is the solution. Keep trying. It's also explained in Professional Excel Development.

Comment: Yes still getting error 438. Continuing to research. What is really getting to me is the error telling me that the object doesn't support the method or property. My instance of the TimeRec object supports the add method I have in there - so  the generic errors are confusing sometimes. As I said before the object I am attempting to add is of the same type as the add method is expecting.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple! uhg.... it was the parenthesis around the add!!!! I removed them and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this particular problem was to remove the parenthesis form my Add method. That being said, the attribute info being hidden was really good info and  would have probably contributed to the problem after I figured out that removing the parenthesis fixed it.